# How can i get this to restart the loop once it hits the last slide?

Tags: jquery

I have these indicators link to each slide but when i reach 11th slide it stops if i continue cycling through the slides all over again. I need it to go back to one after it hits the 12th. can any one help.

```
for (var i = 1; i <= 12; i++) {
    if (jQuery('#slide-' + i).is(':visible')) {
    console.log('#slide-' + i);
    jQuery('#page_count-' + i).addClass('active');
} else {
    jQuery('#page_count-' + i).removeClass('active');
   };
};
```

i have tried:
    if (i = 12) { 
        i = 1;
         };

but it breaks the page .... any ideas?

Comment: try changing it to ``if(i===12){i=1;}``. Do know that the way your for loop is set-up now, it'll cause an infinite loop, which may overload your javascript engine and make your browser unresponsive.

Comment: Seeing so many people just copying his mistakes. setTimeout/setInterval, people!

Comment: +1 for providing both code and causing a bit of debate :)

Comment: Yeah, a loop is really meant for processing things as quickly as possible, not for timed visual events.

Comment: Given the amount of confusion over the *actual* question, I would suggest a JSFiddle in future to demonstrate the intended aim.

Answer (score 2):

Personally, I would use a recursive function for this instead of a loop.

```
var current_slide = 1;
var number_of_slides = 3;
var time_between_slides = 3000; // ms
var nextSlide = function() {

    // do your stuff that changes slides here

    if (current_slide < number_of_slides) {
        current_slide++;
    } else {
        current_slide = 1;
    }

    window.setTimeout(function() {
        nextSlide() // function calls its self, creating an "infinite loop"
    }, time_between_slides);
};
window.setTimeout(function() {
    nextSlide(); // initially call the function to go to the next slide
}, time_between_slides);
```

Comment: Why recursion with ``setTimeout`` rather than just using ``setInterval`` ?

Comment: @Kippie - I use setTimeout because before I have the function call its self again, I can have it check to see if the slideshow has entered "pause mode."

Comment: @TrueBlueAussie fyi, it's still an infinite loop but delayed :)

Comment: @xFortyFourx: It is not an infinite loop... it is an event driven callback that happens to call itself... huge difference :)

Comment: @xFortyFourx Actually it's not. The function queues up a new call with ``setTimeout``, but immediately returns and gives back control to the main javaScript thread.

Answer (score 0):

```
    function repeat(i) {
        i++;

        if (jQuery('#slide-' + i).is(':visible')) {
            console.log('#slide-' + i);
            jQuery('#page_count-' + i).addClass('active');
        } else {
            jQuery('#page_count-' + i).removeClass('active');
           };
         i = i % 12;
         if( i == 0 ) {
             setTimeout(function() {
              repeat(0);
             },5000); // delay of 5 seconds.
         }
         else {

           repeat(i);
         }
    }

repeat(0);
```

EDIT: Like  TrueBlueAussie suggested, removed the loop solution.

EDIT 2: Silly logical errors, fixed, again thanks to TrueBlueAussie.
This will run the first 12 calls quickly, and then delayed for 5 seconds and 
restarts.

Comment: Second answer better, but for goodness sake remove your first answer (it will do nothing except update classes 1000's of times per second... effectively doing nothing) :)

Comment: thank you all for your quick responses .... i will implement your ideas and see what i get . thanks again

Comment: You can get the same numeric wrap around with `i = (i-1) % 12 + 1`. Also did you intend to pass 1 or i in the timer callback? Something odd going on there.

Comment: with this now my page wont load. i think im going to try adding this     if(i===12){i=1;}